# In Angular component, link doesnt work with first time. How can it fix?

Tags: angular, typescript, button, hyperlink, lazy-loading

When I try click one of the array heroes elements in Angular - with first time click doesn't work, only works the second time.
How can fix? Why it happens?
That is method onSelect5() with first time doesnt work.
I add link on github.com where all code:
[1]: https://github.com/site50/Angular-FETCH-an-fetch/tree/main/src/app

Answer (score 0):

In file src/app/heroes/heroes.component.html, line 7, you have

```
      <a routerLink="{{'../' + hero.id}}">
```

but should have

```
      <a routerLink="{{ hero.id }}">
```

the reason is that angular routing is trying to go to a previous route but the previous root is this page, and therefore the second time you land here, you are in the correct route and can go the '/{hero.id}' page (as specified in the routing file).

Comment: I tryed it, all work, but get a message in the console "core.mjs:7635 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'heroes/box/6'
Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'heroes/box/6'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.mjs:3644:16)
    at router.mjs:3626:28
    at catchError.js:10:39
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (OperatorSubscriber.js:23:21) "

Comment: I think it happens then using "[class.selected]="hero === selectedHero" (click)="onSelect5(hero)"".